# Unable to perform json.loads(json_data) when calling from parent classes

Tags: python, json

I forgot to mention, I'm using the following CURL to send the data:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET "http://appdev1.ischoolcampus.com/api/assignments" -d '{"guid":"teacherones-class","isTeacher":0}'
```

I have a method Assignments.GET() that send some data and the format of the data (JSON, XML, etc.) to...

ClientRequest.Receive(data,method) which based on the format, sends it to another method in ClientRequest...

JSON(data) decodes the data using iSCJSON.Decode(data)...

json.loads(data) should spit it out as a dictionary, but instead it is giving me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loads'
```

Each class is in a different module:

```
Assignments - imports:
  ClientRequest - imports:
    iSCJSON.
```

I have tried this by just calling iSCJSON.Decode(json_data) from Assignments and it worked fine. I have checked to make sure that json_data actually has content once it drills all the way down, and it does.

But for some reason I still receive an error.

Any ideas?

Classes:

**Assignments**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1,'/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/iconnect/')

import web

if 'iSCModules.mod_ClientRequest' in sys.modules:  
    del(sys.modules["iSCModules.mod_ClientRequest"])

if 'iSCModules.mod_ServerResponse' in sys.modules:  
    del(sys.modules["iSCModules.mod_ServerResponse"])

from iSCModules.mod_ClientRequest import ClientRequest
from iSCModules.mod_ServerResponse import ServerResponse
#from iSCModules.mod_iSCJSON import iSCJSON

class Assignments:
    def GET(self):
        sentData = web.data()
        #query = iSCJSON.Decode(sentData)
        print "Sent Data is: " + sentData
        query = ClientRequest.Receive(sentData, 'JSON')
        # \/ Replace With Code \/
        print "Query from Assignments is: " + query
        data = query 
        # /\ Replace with Code /\
        return ServerResponse.Send(data, 'JSON')
```

**ClientRequest**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1,'/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/iconnect/')

import web

#if 'iSCModules.mod_iSCJSON' in sys.modules:  
#    del(sys.modules["iSCModules.mod_iSCJSON"])

from mod_iSCJSON import iSCJSON

class ClientRequest:
    @staticmethod
    def Receive(data, method):
        #sentData = web.data() #Need to figure out why this doesn't work...
        # Remove method from parameters, Set method using logic to determine format of data sent from client. 
        query = getattr(ClientRequest, method)(data)
        if (query):
            print "Query from ClientRequest is: " + query
            return query

    @staticmethod
    def JSON(data):
        decodedData = iSCJSON.Decode(data)
        if (decodedData):
            return decodedData
```

**iSCJSON**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1,'/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/iconnect/')

import json

class iSCJSON:
    @staticmethod
    def Encode(json_string, compact=False):
        if (compact):
            result = json.dumps(json_string,separators=(',',':'))
        else:
            result = json.dumps(json_string)
        if ( result ):
            return result

    @staticmethod
    def Decode(json_data, encoding=''):
        print "JSON Data is: " + json_data
        result = json.loads(json_data)
        print "Result of iSCJSON is: " + result
        if ( result ):
            return result
```

Comment: Are you missing `import json` in your `ISCJSON` class file?

Comment: No, I probably should've included that part of code. I've double, and triple checked to make sure I have the proper imports.

Comment: @favoretti The thing that is so strange is that in the Decode method, where I have print "JSON Data is: " + json_data... It prints the correct information, but the next line it fails with the error listed above.

Comment: yeah, it can't find the import. Can you include that import statement you have in your code snipped by editing your post?

Comment: and another question, which of your modules imports json? and what's the exact import line? On a second note - what's the point of using classes if all if your methods are static? :)

Comment: I may not need to have the JSON methods in a Class, but it allows me to import them easily into all of the different classes I have. I'm trying to come up with the best way to built my RESTful API.
I'll updated my Post with the remainder of the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The error message implies that `json is None`. Perhaps you use `json` as a variable name, shadowing the module of the same name?

Answer (score 0):

So, I've come up with a way to solve this by combining two classes into one module and reducing the number of methods. I've combined ClientRequest and another class ServerResponse into one class called Server, this class performs the function of both with only two methods, Send and Receive. The two methods then determine what class to call: iSCJSON or iSCXML to do the encoding and decoding. So, I have remedied the problem without actually solving it, with less code.